# How set up todo list categories in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How set up todo list categories in Delphi 2010.  This syntax does not work:

```
// TODO 1 -cImportant: Do this!
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, copied as-is. In what way does it fail for you?

Answer (score 6):

In Delphi 2007, these two syntaxes are recognized:

```
{ TODO 1  -cImportant :Do this!}
// TODO 1 -cImportant: Do this!
```

Try launch TODO via dialog pressing SHIFT+CTRL+T keys. Fill dialog and see how Delphi introduces TODO in code.

Comment: The important thing is the colon somewhere after the TODO. If you do not have the colon, then the TODO list will not show the comment. Anything after the colon will be the `action item` in the TODO list.

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi XE2, I created 2 todo comments, one manually and one via Shift-CTRL-T. They didn't appear in the opened TODO list. I save, close and reopen the file and the comments popsup in the TODO list. Thenafter, the TODO list worked very well in a completely syncronized way.